# How can my app distinguish between Windows 10 and Windows 11?

Tags: windows

I use Windows 11 but all apps I install report that I am running Windows 10. How can applications read the correct OS data for Windows 11?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11's version number is very similar. It's still major version 10, minor version 0. The difference between "Windows 10" and "Windows 11" is the build number being larger 22000. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/windows-sdk-for-windows-11/).

Basically, unless the application was updated to *know* about Windows 11, it's going to think it's Windows 10.

> It's also important to note that for application compatibility between major versions of Windows, many existing applications are subject an automatic "shim" that lies about the version number in any case. For more, see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/whats-in-a-version-number/).